# 'SelectionColor' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Tags: vb.net

I have a richtextbox in my designer and I have this code

```
 Imports System.Drawing

 'Some codes here
 'Some codes here
 'Some codes here
 'Some codes here

 rtbDisplay.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Then whenever I run the application I received this error

```
'SelectionColor' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.
```

Although I already import `Imports System.Drawing` I still received this kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

I just realized that rtbDisplay is a `textbox` not a `richtextbox`. That's why it doesnt know `SelectionColor`.